# Problem importing Flutter project From Windows to Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I'm trying to import a flutter project developed with intellij on windows into Xcode
Here is the project hierarchy
[image]

My flutter project works great in intellij on windows as well as on android phones. Now I would like to test on iPhone.
I manage to open the project under Xcode but I don't see the "lib" folder which contains all the dart code.
So how to build for iOS, in other words, how to generate an iOS app from my dart code.
It is impossible to code in dart in Xcode, so i suppose Xcode is just use to build with command line in console mode ?
Flutter is a cross platform technology but it seems very complicated for me from the moment i tried to build for iOS.